# Is it possible to write to the Boot Camp disk in OS X?

Tags: bootcamp

I have a MacBook Pro with Boot Camp and sometimes I want to update information on the Windows partition but currently I have to boot in Windows and read from the Mac partition.  I don't want to leave OS X to organize files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible.

You will first need [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) and then [NTFS-3G](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/NTFS-3G.shtml).

The User's Guide for NTFS-3G can be found [here](http://hem.bredband.net/catacombae/ntfs-3g/macntfs-3g_userguide.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: Just be aware of the bug that the Boot Camp partition sometimes disappears from the startup disk screen. I recommend using refit if your going to use NTFS-3G.